# Hide table row from other Users In Database if it is access by User

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have an table on which multiple records.
if  user(A) get record from table then others user can not get that record particular record that is retrieve by User(A) what should i do to reslove this

Comment: And for ***what database system*** is this? SQL is just the query language - not a concrete product - and these things are usually **highly** vendor-specific

Comment: to marc_s
em using SQL server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `locked` bool column to the table, to signify that the record is locked by some user. Rather than a bool, you can reference the user_id that has locked the row. You'll have to do this in your application code, since sql-server cannot do this work for you out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

As i see in your comment,You can create new column or table to store id of user and flag accessed in that. While accessing records use this relationship.

Or please elaborate your question and if possible provide an table structure

Comment: ok but need clarification about question because  i was not able to get understand the question whether he wants an lock or referential entry

Comment: If you don't have enough information to answer his question you should add comments to his question before submitting an answer. Just giving you friendly advice on how to become the accepted one.

Comment: thanks to remind me but i think refferntial solution can help